# Unmet dependencies issue with Python

Tags: package-management, python, dependencies

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` produces

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pil
 python-imaging-tk
 python-imaging
 python-pil.imagetk
 python-setuptools
```

and running `sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade` produces

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-imaging-tk : Depends: python-pil.imagetk (>= 2.3.0-1ubuntu3.3) but 2.3.0-1ubuntu3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

How do I correct these unmet dependencies? I believe I may have botched an attempt at installing Python 3.

Thanks!

EDIT 1: Hmm, after following minigeek's steps I appear to have made the situation worse. Now running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` produces

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hplip-data
 python-pil
 python-pil.imagetk
 python-imaging
 python-pexpect
 python-reportlab
 python-setuptools
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing this by going to Synaptic and manually upgrading the packages listed above (python-pil, python-imaging, etc.). Fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

First run

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove <package name>
```

If it doesn't work then

```
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install anything!